# Opening a new terminal tab based on the current one

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've added the following keybinding in vscode to open a new terminal window:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.new"
}
```

When I execute a command like `cd Desktop` then run `cmd+t` again while still in it, the new terminal starts from zero. Is it possible for the new terminal to be based on the previous one? meaning in our case it should open a new terminal tab that runs on `/Desktop` instead of the root directory.

I am using bash.

Comment: Have a look at the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here It creates a new terminal bases on the folder of the file you have active in the editor.  Possibly of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your User Settings (Menu:File > Preferences):

```
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "Desktop"
```

This will now open up in Desktop instead of having to cd into it.

I'm not sure how to change the cwd based on other open terminals per your question.Here's the full commented setting in vscode:

> // An explicit start path where the terminal will be launched, this is
>   used as the current working directory (cwd) for the shell process.
>   This may be particularly useful in workspace settings if the root
>   directory is not a convenient cwd.
>
> "terminal.integrated.cwd": "",